# What libraries is my program accessing?

Tags: java, glassfish, classloader

Hello I have a Java web application which has been deployed on a remote glassfish server. This server contains some libraries which may be required by the Java code. My Java code, however, also generates similar kind of libraries at compile time. Now I am not sure if my code is using the libraries on the server or the libraries that were generated at compile time because it is a big project and a lot of the code was not written by me. Any idea how I can figure out what libraries  my code is using?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can run java with the argument `-verbose:class`. This will make it print out information from the classloader as libraries are loaded. Not sure if this will work with the classloader glassfish uses though. Try that first. If it doesn't work look into how to get debug logging from the glassfish classloader.

This shows how to add JVM arguments with glassfish: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gepzd.html